# pyqt / getting heap out of memory when trying to compile ui.c

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pyqt, pyqt5

i have made a ui using pyqt with a lot of qstackedwidgets and qpushbuttons.

the ui itself has about 500kb. when i try setup.py build_ext --inplace i get ui.c(1278): fatal

error C1060 heap out of memory.

i tried putting below in setup.py as someone suggested. it doesnt give me the error but instead it

would almost freeze my computer and i dont know why.

```
from distutils import _msvccompiler
_msvccompiler.PLAT_TO_VCVARS['win-amd64'] = 'amd64'
```

is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Why are you doing that? If your program is PyQt based, what would be the point of using and compiling the `ui.c` file? Just generate the UI with pyuic and use that.

Comment: @musicamante it is actaully a py file, but i encrypted it and changed it to pyx and trying to compile it as c cause its good for source protection

Comment: "source protection" over the Ui seems a pointless and exaggerated effort, especially if done like that: at that point, just encrypt the ui file and decode it at runtime. Besides, *how* are you changing it to pyx?